# What is accurate GLONASS?

Tags: gps, satellite

As I know, GPS gives accurate data for everyone.

I've heard GLONASS have two types of data.

1. High precision data available only for the Military.
2. Low precision data for civilians.

İs there an visible difference, is it similar to the Selective Availability protocols from pre 2000?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be no marked difference between what GPS and GLONASS can provide. Both systems can be used for precise point positioning, and civilians have access to dual frequencies. There are restricted signals but even then you can achieve excellent results.

There are still restricted signals broadcast by GPS sats with encoding released only to authorized parties. It should be similar to what the Russians do, they are both dual-use systems.

Check [this page](http://everything.explained.today/GLONASS/) for a summary of the system.

Comment: So they have an backup system if they decide to cut off the system for their enemies?